# Python libraries imported but unused

Tags: python, pandas

The code is actually re-written from an application that worked
Using the latest version of python via Anaconda and Spyder ide
With Spyder
   [code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxgeS.jpg)

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import os
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import sklearn.metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

Code analysis show pandas library imported but unused.

Please help out a python noobie

thanks for the comments, I'm learning!!

I have run the script both with and without the imports as suggested and the console return the errors as seen in the SS[console error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0sIn.jpg)

```
>>> runfile('C:/Users/dbldee/Desktop/TREES/Decisiontree.py', wdir='C:/Users/dbldee/Desktop/TREES')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dbldee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dbldee\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/dbldee/Desktop/TREES/Decisiontree.py", line 42, in <module>
    classifier = classifier.fit(pred_train,tar_train)
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
>>>
```

Which suggests that the problem may be with reading of the file??

Comment: You should be able to remove these imports, although you should test your code afterwards to ensure this doesn't cause any unexpected problems.

Comment: Could you provide an example -in case you are getting a problem with those imports?

Comment: @flippy,  This part of script appears to be the source of problems that prevent execution<from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import sklearn.metrics


os.chdir('C:\\Users\\dbldee\\Desktop\\TREES')
"""
Data Engineering and Analysis
"""
#Load the dataset

AH_data = pd.read_csv("tree_addhealth.csv")

Answer (score 2):

Spyder is doing a [static check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_static_checking) to help with the correctness of your python program. You probably can run it just fine as it is, but the tool is helping you with python style and conciseness.

Try removing the line

```
import pandas as pd
```

and it should stop complaining. Try breaking and changing the program following the ide's suggestions without fear to break the program, that is what will make you learn.

Comment: I really think people rely way to much on there IDE's/text editor these days. +1 for telling him not to be afraid of going against the IDE's advice and just seeing what happens. You should know why your doing something, rather then just blindly doing it.